# Can I assign or add tags to an Azure Policy, Initiative or Azure Policy Assignments?

Tags: azure-policy

I need to add metadata to an Azure Policy, Initiative  or Azure Policy Assignments.

Is it possible to assign or add tags to an Azure Policy, Initiative  or Azure Policy Assignments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-support) you will find the list of resources that support tags.

What do you want to achieve by tagging Azure Policies/ Initiatives/ Assignments? What is your goal?

Comment: I wanted to add metadata to an Azure Policy, or a Policy Assignment. What are my options?

Comment: use description field